# how can I create session in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

Here is my code. jquery.session.js file is also loaded I could not get where is the problem. Can you Please tell me the solution.

```
$.session.set('rmng_time', remaining_seconds);
        alert("j session  "+$.session.get('rmng_time'));
```

> > this code gives an error in console 
> >     TypeError: $.session is undefined

Comment: try `sessionStorage.setItem('rmng_time', remaining_seconds);`

Comment: which means the plugin is not loaded. check if jquery is loaded. if jquery is loaded then check jquery.session is loaded

Comment: i check every thing is fine but TypeError: $.session is undefined is showing

Answer (score 5):

You need to reffer this tutorial:

http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/create-session-with-jquery/

Add required files and refer code -

```
jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery.session.js
```

ex.

To set session:

```
$(function() {
 $.session.set("myVar", "Hello World!");
});
```

To get session:

```
alert($.session.get("myVar"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery session. See here in the [docs](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.session.js).

```
$.session.set('some key', value);
console.log($.session.get('mobile_no'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(function() {
    $.session.set("myVar", "value");
});


// To Read
$(function() {
    alert($.session.get("myVar"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to include the jquery session library files to run the $.session.
so, follow this link http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/01/20/session-handling-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the some specific data to the active session like
`sessionStorage.setItem("loginData",JSON.stringify(logObj));`

And you can access the the stored data from the session like :-

`sessionStorage.loginData`